# Identity with variable seed

Tags: sql, t-sql, variables, dynamic, identity

I have this code, i'm trying to set the identity seed by a varable

```
DECLARE @iKeyX INT

SELECT @iKeyX = MAX(KeyX) FROM Temporales..tmp_Orders

IF (@iKeyX = NULL)
   SET @iKeyX = 1
ELSE
   SET @iKeyX = @iKeyX + 1

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_Orders','U') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #tmp_Orders

SELECT  IDENTITY(INT, @iKeyX, 1) AS KeyX,
        0 AS Valido, 
        OrderNumber, 
        OrderType, 
        Code, 
        Size, 
INTO #tmp_Orders
FROM TableWithData
```

Why SQL keeps telling me "Incorrect syntax near '@ iKeyX'"?

Comment: I am making an assumption here that `IDENTITY` can't take a variable as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an [old bug](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/271827) in SQL Server that has never been fixed.  To work around the problem (as suggested in the link), build the command into a string and then execute the string.

Workaround from the link:

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(8000)
DECLARE @myident int
SET @myident = 100
SET @sql = 'SELECT IDENTITY(INT, ' + CAST(@myident as varchar) + ', 1)    AS ident INTO #T2'
EXEC(@sql)
SELECT @@identity
```

Answer (score 1):

Because I don't like adding statements into a string..
I ended up doing the following:

```
DECLARE @NewId INT

SELECT @NewId = MAX(ID) FROM MyIDSTable

DECLARE @MyTempData TABLE (
    Id int not null primary key
    ,Field1 int not null
    ,Field2 nvarchar(25) not null
    ,Field3 datetime
)

INSERT INTO @MyTempData
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( Order by [C].[Cancel_id] ASC) + @NewId -1 [RowNum]
        ,Field1
        ,Field2
        ,Field3

INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT * FROM @MyTempData

UPDATE MYIDSTable SET ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @MyTempData) + 1 WHERE Name = 'Something'
```

Thank you